# Play 2.5 WSClient SSL Mutual Authentication SelfSigned certificate

Tags: java, scala, ssl, playframework, playframework-2.5

I am trying to use play's ws client to make an https request to a server that requires mutual authentication. 
I have followed play's documentation here https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ExampleSSLConfig
and added my cert (self signed was given) and key. However when I make a call with the WS Client I get error such as

```
 CompositeCertificateException: No trust manager was able to validate 
this certificate chain: # of exceptions
```

In my debugging I see that for the key I get a "found key for" message and also for the cert  I see a message saying the cert was added. However it still gives me that exception?

I know it is not a problem with those two since I have made a curl request with both the cert and key and the mutual auth request for the curl request worked.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?